# Port Forwarding puzzle

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a puzzle that I need help with.

We have two PLCs, each with a built-in webserver. They have been assigned IPs of 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.1.8. They talk to each other via Ethernet and are connected through a switch. The switch is also connected to a consumer-grade Asus router which connects to a cable modem. We have paid extra for a static IP.

If I connect a laptop to the router I can access either PLC by entering the IP in my browser. If I set up Port Forwarding to allow access to 192.168.1.5 from the internet I can connect to the PLC from outside the network just fine. But if I change the Port Forwarding settings to access 192.168.1.8 I get a “Server not responding” error.

I can’t understand why one works and the other doesn’t. Especially since they both work fine through the router.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't this question belong in SuperUser?

Comment: Try putting 192.168.1.8 in the DMZ temporarily to eliminate any firewall issues in the router. That will help point you in the direction on what the problem is.

Comment: If you put PLC’s open for internet access, take appropiate security measures. Your PKC might become vunerable to hacking and DDOS attacks. See for example [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.579.3650&rep=rep1&type=pdf). A good practice is to only allow access via a trusted VPN.

Comment: Dan, I tried adding 192.168.1.8 to the DMZ with no luck.

Comment: agtoever, I’m only forwarding http traffic and there is no way to control processes remotely. A DDOS attack would be annoying but it wouldn’t affect our operations. Still, an interesting read, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Seem like to me you forgot to add a default gateway in that PLC.

Comment: The system worked before we replaced the router. The old router was set up for a VPN connection. The new one is not. Wouldn’t the PLC need to have the correct Default Gateway for a VPN setup?

Comment: @mmesford If the VPN give the remote user an local IP, no, that would still work even without the gateway, can you validate the setting in that PLC ?

Comment: I haven’t been able to access the network configuration for the PLC. I’ll have to talk to tech support. Standby.